# Working with Promises in AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm migrating some code from Silverlight to AngularJS. My Silverlight code would basically attempt to hit a web service. If it failed, it would wait a bit and try again. It would try this three times. I'm now trying to do this in AngularJS.

From my understanding, I should use an AngularJS service to hit my web service. From my understanding, promises are used. At this time, I have the following service:

```
'use strict';
myApp.service('$myService', function($rootScope, $http) {
  this.queryAttempt = 0;
  this.findRecent = function() {
    this.queryAttempt = 0;
  };

  this.attemptToGetRecent = function() {
    try {
      this.queryAttempt = this.queryAttempt + 1;
      if (this.recentQueryAttempt < 3) {
        $http.get('http://www.someserver.com/endpoint');        
      } else {
        console.log('signal failure');
      }
    } catch (ex1) {
      console.log('Error Finding Recent (2).');
    }
  };
});
```

Due to the fact that promises are used, I'm a little lost. In Silverlight, I created events. My controller will call $myService.findRecent(). I want to detect success and failure. However, I also need some retry logic in there. If I didn't need the retry logic, I would just use return $http.get(...) in the findRecent function. However, with the retry logic need, I don't know how to structure my promises such that the controller is aware of a) a success and b) a failure if three attempts have been tried and failed.

Can someone show me how to tackle this scenario in the world of promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me post the code how to do it with comment below:

```
myApp.service('myService', function($rootScope, $http, $q) {

    var findRecent - function() {

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        attemptToGetRecent(0, deferred);

        return deferred.promise;
    };


    var attemptToGetRecent = function(count, deferred) {
        $http.get('http://www.someserver.com/endpoint')
             .success(function (response) {
                deferred.resolve(response);
             })
             .error(function() {
                if (count >= 3) {
                    deferred.reject();
                } else {
                    attemptToGetRecent(count++, deffered);
                }
             });
    };
});
```

1. In your service get instance of `$q` service, create deferred object
   (a promise) yourself.
2. Pass it as a parameter to `attemptToGetRecent` function which will
   keep calling itself recursively until the number of efforts is too
   high.
3. Function `attemptToGetRecent` will try to call the server, if
   success it resolves your promise with the data. If the call fails,
   it will be called again up to 3 timers then rejecting your promise

Consumer of this code would use it this way:

```
myService.findRecent()    
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.videos = data.feed.entry;
      }, function() {
        console.log("error");
      });       
    };
```

For easier reading I removed logging with console. That can be added of course. Also it is a good habit to not name your own services with leading $, this is reserved to angular services.

**Working example:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KnCFJ

Comment: When I execute this code, I get an unhandled exception. It has to do with the consumer code. The service code seems to be working just fine. However, neither the .success | .error code gets called in the consumer. I just see "undefined is not a function" in the console window.

Comment: I misstyped deferred in the findRecent function. The rest of the code seems to be ok. Please debug it and check what exactly is undefined or if you can provide a fiddle. Thanks!

Comment: I had fixed the deferred error before posting my comment. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the debugger to tell me what is undefined.

Comment: I am on phone now, I can create working fiddle for you tomorrow if it helps

Comment: I created a Pen that tries to hit YouTube and bring back basketball videos. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iqEyx.

Comment: I would appreciate any help I can get. I can't figure out why its not working.

Comment: Will so tomorrow. I am just on phone and its difficult :)

Comment: There were some typos in the code. I edited my answer and appended working example. The link is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KnCFJ

Comment: Thank you so much for sticking with this!

Answer (score 0):

You can inject $q and use it to make your own promise and create a recursive function to handle the attempts.

Here is some code that should help:

```
'use strict';
myApp.service('$myService', function ($rootScope, $http, $q) {
    this.getRecent = function(){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var attempts = 0;
        (function queryRecent(attempts, error){
            if(attempts >= 2){
                // the $http.get() failed 3 times
                deferred.reject(error);
            }else{
                $http.get('http://www.someserver.com/endpoint').then(function(response){
                    // success -> resolve any data you want
                    deferred.resolve({
                        attempts: attempts,
                        response: response
                    });
                }).catch(function(error){
                    // failed, retry the queryRecent recursive function
                    queryRecent(attempts + 1, error); // pass attempts + 1 and the error object
                });
            }
        })(attempts, ''); // initially pass 0 and '' to the queryRecent recursive function
        return deferred.promise;
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $myService){
    $myService.getRecent().then(function(data){
        // success -> use data
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(error){
        // the $http.get() failed 3 times
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```